# How to delete rows from a table based on a join with another table?

Tags: mysql

The setup is this:

table B has a column named task and another keyid

table C has columns keyid and type.

What I want to do is delete all entries in B such that B.task = C.keyid and C.type='1'. If I wanted to select the rows to delete the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM B,C
WHERE B.task=C.keyid
AND C.type='1'
```

I have tried a couple of options the latest one being:

```
DELETE FROM B    
WHERE keyid IN (SELECT B.keyid FROM B,C
                WHERE B.task=C.keyid
                AND C.type='1');
```

Which gets me the error "You can't specify target table 'B' for update in FROM clause"

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `explicit` join instead of `implicit join` and you can use join for delete as below

```
delete b_t from B b_t
join C c_t on b_t.task = c_t.keyid
where c_t.type = 1 ;
```

Comment: You may need to give `b_t` after `delete b_t from B` in your sql query.